# Configuration proxy due iptables

Tags: linux, tcp, proxy, port, iptables

i have to configure my server to redirect from 80 and 443 port due to 8443 using iptables

```
          -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
          -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
          -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
          -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
          -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80:443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
```

when i browse like https protocol everything is working, but when from http, i can just donwnload a file, and don't see anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`8443` port is intended mainly to use as **HTTPS** proxy. Sending **plain HTTP** to this port will not work. You should keep separated HTTP and HTTPS traffic by sending them to a different port (normally 8080) of your transparent proxy.

Answer (score 0):

using this rule :
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80:443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443

you allowed only incoming traffic to to be sent to port 8443, but still the outgoing traffic needs to be routed